# Assigning group-specific dispersion parameters in a negative binomial mixed model

Tags: r, mixed-models

I have (overdispersed) count data that are collected at different facilities that I want to model using a negative binomial random effect model, with a random effect for facility. On further inspection of the data, overdispersion varies widely for each facility (ie, the distribution of the outcome in some facilities approximates Poisson, others are highly overdispersed, some are in between), ie:

[image]

I would like to specify the dispersion for each group within the model. I tried using the `GLMMadaptive::mixed_model`, as it has parameters `n_phis` and `initial_values` which the documentation specifies allows you to put in how many parameters and their initial values, so I estimated the dispersion parameter (`szs`) via `MASS:fitdistr` and tried to plug them in:

```
szs <- sapply(unique(dta$facility), \(i) MASS::fitdistr(dta$outcome[dta$facility == i], "negative binomial")[[1]][1])

GLMMadaptive::mixed_model(fixed = outcome ~ phase,
                          random = ~ 1|facility,
                          data = dta,
                          n_phis = length(unique(dta$facility)),
                          initial_values = szs, # also tried initial_values = c(phis = szs) given the function documentation
                          family = GLMMadaptive::negative.binomial())
```

However that was unsuccessful as it still models using a single dispersion parameter (removing the `n_phis` and `initial_values` commands returns the exact same model). I did not see any options for this type of thing in `lme4::glmer.nb`.

After some searching, I see that this can be done via a Bayesian approach in the `brms` package (Cross Validated questions [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/568047/how-to-develop-a-negative-binomial-model-where-the-overdispersion-parameter-vari/568052#568052) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/625131/poisson-or-negative-binomial-regression-when-within-cluster-data-follow-differen)), but can this be done using packages that use other methods (ie, `GLMMadaptive::mixed_model`, `lme4::glmer.nb`, or another package)? To be clear, my question is about the coding implementation, not the underlying statistical concept.

---

Data

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 100
dta <- data.frame(facility = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = n),
                  phase = rep(c("Intervention", "Control"), each = n / 2),
                  outcome = c(rnbinom(n, mu = 5, size = 0.02), 
                              rpois(n, lambda = 5),
                              rpois(n, lambda = 8), 
                              rnbinom(n, mu = 8, size = 0.5)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do this in `glmmTMB`, with `dispformula` (see code and results below).

- the `n_phis` parameter in `mixed_model()` doesn't do what you think it does: this describes the number of parameters required for dispersion and shape parameters for a particular family (e.g. 0 for Poisson, 1 for neg binom, 2 for Tweedie)
- this particular model is a little bit weird; it uses a random effect for the mean (location) by group, but a fixed effect for the dispersion/scale by group (at present `glmmTMB` doesn't allow random effects in the dispersion model, e.g. `dispformula = ~ 1|facility)`, even if that might sometimes make sense ...)
- according to comments in the linked CV question, this should also be possible via `VGAM::negbinomial()` ...

```r
library(glmmTMB)
m <- glmmTMB(outcome ~ phase + (1|facility),
             dispformula  = ~ facility,
             data = dta,
             family = nbinom2)
```

```
Formula:          outcome ~ phase + (1 | facility)
Dispersion:               ~facility
Data: dta
      AIC       BIC    logLik  df.resid 
1684.8276 1712.7678 -835.4138       393 
Random-effects (co)variances:

Conditional model:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
 facility (Intercept) 0.2193  

Number of obs: 400 / Conditional model: facility, 4

Fixed Effects:

Conditional model:
      (Intercept)  phaseIntervention  
          1.89473           -0.01547  

Dispersion model:
(Intercept)    facilityB    facilityC    facilityD  
     -4.279        9.191       10.154        3.657
```